# How to conditionally expose data in Spring Data REST projection?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

There is a projection `UserProjection` and the `User` table has field - `enable_email`, a boolean.

```
@Projection(name = "summary", types = User.class)
public interface UserSummaryProjection {

    String getEmail();
}
```

Visiting URL `/app/users/{id}?projection=summary` shows the email as expected

1. How can the summary projection be configured to return the email only if `enable_email` is `true`?
2. Also will that configuration only affect this projection or be applicable across all projections for the `User` entity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In projection, it was only a matter of annotating with `@Value` with Spring bean and method name as below:

```
@Value("#{@userUtil.manageEmail(target)}")
String getEmail();
```

Then, I created a Spring Bean annotated with the `@Component` annotation and added the method below:

```
public String manageEmail(User user) {
    Profile profile = profileRepo.findByUser(user);
    String[] paramsEnabled = profile.getSettings().split(",");
    boolean emailAllowed = Arrays.stream(paramsEnabled).anyMatch((s) -> (s.equals(Constants.EMAIL_ENABLED)));

    return  emailAllowed ? user.getEmail() : null;
}
```

Comment: If you can answer the question on whether to expose the email address from the user instance alone, you can even simplify the SpEL expression to `#{target.exposeEmail() ? target.email : null}`.

Comment: So, and your sourrounding class is `@Component public class userUtil {}`, or what else?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the [Spring documantation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/3.2/repositories/projections.html)

**Example image**

[image]

You can create a `@Component` with `@Value` annotation for complex logic

```
@Component
class MyBean {

  String getFullName(Person person) {
    …
  }
}

interface NamesOnly {

  @Value("#{@myBean.getFullName(target)}")
  String getFullName();
  …
}
```